# numpy: ndenumerate for masked arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to enumerate over the non-masked locations of a masked `numpy ndarray` (e.g. in the way that `ndenumerate` does it for regular `ndarrays`, but omitting all the masked entries)?

EDIT: to be more precise: the enumeration should not only skip over the masked entries, but also show the indices of the non-masked ones in the original array. E.g. if the first five elements of a 1-d array are masked, and the next one has an unmasked value of 3, then the enumeration should start with something like `((5,), 3), ...`.

Thanks!

PS: note that, although it is possible to apply `ndenumerate` to a masked `ndarray`, the resulting enumeration does not discriminate between its masked and normal entries. In fact, `ndenumerate` not only does not filter out the masked entries from the enumeration, but it doesn't even replace the enumerated values with the `masked` constant. Therefore, one can't adapt `ndenumerate` for this task by just wrapping `ndenumerate` with a suitable filter.

Comment: look at the compressed function of ma arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

def maenumerate(marr):
    mask = ~marr.mask.ravel()
    for i, m in itertools.izip(np.ndenumerate(marr), mask):
        if m: yield i

N = 12
a = np.arange(N).reshape(2, 2, 3)+10

b = np.ma.array(a, mask = (a%5 == 0))
for i, val in maenumerate(b):
    print i, val
```

which yields

```
(0, 0, 1) 11
(0, 0, 2) 12
(0, 1, 0) 13
(0, 1, 1) 14
(1, 0, 0) 16
(1, 0, 1) 17
(1, 0, 2) 18
(1, 1, 0) 19
(1, 1, 2) 21
```

Comment: This solution still works, but note that itertools.izip needs to be replaced with zip in python3.

Answer (score 8):

You can access only valid entries using **inverse of a mask** as an index:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import numpy.ma as ma
>>> x = np.array([11, 22, -1, 44])
>>> m_arr = ma.masked_array(x, mask=[0, 0, 1, 0])
>>> for index, i in np.ndenumerate(m_arr[~m_arr.mask]): 
        print index, i
(0,) 11
(1,) 22
(2,) 44
```

See [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) for details.

The enumeration over only valid entries with indices from the original array:

```
>>> for (index, val), m in zip(np.ndenumerate(m_arr), m_arr.mask):
      if not m:
        print index, val 
(0,) 11
(1,) 22
(3,) 44
```